# How to display two images on the same line (CSS)

Tags: html, css, virtual

I'm currently skinning site for a virtual airline and I need help as to how to get
two images to show up on the same line instead of one breaking onto the next line.

It should be displayed as:

> LOGO             ICON

But instead it turns into:

> ```
>                ICON
> ```
>
> LOGO

Does anyone know how to fix this in the CSS?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, could you provide a jsFiddle?  Some actual code would be useful.

Comment: What about float left/right?

Comment: I use float right to make it appear to the right, the thing I'm trying to do is put it on the same line as another image on the left margin.

Comment: Here is the CSS and layout.tpl: [link](http://klmgefs.zzl.org/lib/skins/klm/layout.tpl) and [link] (http://klmgefs.zzl.org/lib/skins/css/default.css)

Comment: So you'd like the icon on the same line as the logo (presuming the site is http://klmgefs.zzl.org/)?

Comment: Yes, icon on same line as logo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I have to admit your HTML is screwed up - inline style declarations, incorrect image links, etc.

Replace the `#top` div with the following in your layout.tpl file:

```php
<!-- Logo + Search + Navigation -->
<div id="top">
    <a id="logo" href="<?php echo SITE_URL?>" target="_blank">
        <img src="/lib/skins/klm/img/logo.png" alt="Home">
    </a>
    <img id="fb" src="http://fc04.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2012/295/0/a/facebook_icon_by_x_1337_x-d5ikwkm.png" alt="Facebook">
</div>
```

Replace the following CSS style declarations with this:

```css
#fb {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline;
    width: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#logo {
    bottom: 0;
    display: inline;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

#top {
    height: 58px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j5ahS/)

You can make a div for each LOGO and ICON and float them.

```
<div class="head">
   <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
   <div class="logo">ICON</div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.head { width:100%;}
.logo {float:left; padding:10px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using links instead of using image tags ,,

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <a class="one"><a class="two"></a></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.one {float:left; background-image: url(../img/logo.png);}
.two {float:right; background-image: url(../img/ico.png);}
```

or if you still want to use the image tag, you can also use this ..

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="one" alt scr="bla">
    <img class="two" alt scr="bla">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {display:table;}
.one, .two {display:table-column;} -or- .one, .two {display:table-cell;}
```

if you're going to change the container's size, sure it must fit both of the images.